# jQuery ajaxForm passes wrong textarea value after codemirror`s save

Tags: jquery, codemirror

Im using jQuery`s ajaxForm method to sumbit my form, I use POST.
There is a textarea input inside the form, I use Codemirror to highlight it.

Before submiting I use Codemirror`s save(),

but it never passes changed value to server (I checked it both server and client side
Post parameter has an old value) So, I guess it is a client-side problem isn`t it?

As you know, Codemirror hides real textarea and generates div on textarea`s place.
If I set the real`s textarea display style to '' before the submit, but after the CodeMirror`s
save method, I see that the real textarea`s value has changed, but, as I said, it never goes to server =(

How could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `.save()` on the CodeMirror instance before triggering your jQuery ajax magic. It is not constantly updating the textarea as you type, for performance reasons. It'll notice submit events on the form, and save, but no such events are triggered when you do an ajax submit.